# restrict filesystem access from CGI

Tags: security, cgi

does anybody know how to restrict access from CGI scripts (python, perl, ruby and so on) to file-system files (/etc/passwd for instance)
So I want to have something like PHP's open_basedir option for CGI

PS
OS hasn't any additional security things like grsecurity, apparmor or selinux

Comment: Yeah you can do this with the usual Linux access controls. (although apparmor and selinux are apart of the linux mainline ;).  But this question is better suited for ServerFault.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to do this:

1. Use [CGIwrap](http://cgiwrap.sourceforge.net/)
2. If you insist on rolling it youself, use `chroot`.
3. Use file system permissions. Have you CGI script run as a specific user, like "restrict1234", and give restrict1234 access to only a specific directory.
4. Use capabilities, if your OS supports them. Lots do.

Comment: 1. as I understood this thing same with suexec... 

2. I have many sites on server ... and I have not a lot of space to chroot each user

3. done

4. can you give an example . for instance how to prevent read /etc/passwd ?

Comment: suexec runs CGIs as different users. So that's okay; just make sure the users don't have the ability to read /etc/passwd. If you want a book that explains this, try Practical UNIX and Internet Security by Garfinkel & Spafford.